# Declared global variable is not working when I use Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have this unit test

```js
import { Service } from './Service';

import * as mysql from 'mysql2/promise';

declare var global;

const config = {
  host: // my host,
  port: // my port,
  user: // my user,
  password: // my password,
  database: //my database
};

describe('Service', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    try {
      global.connectionPool = mysql.createPool(config);
      return global.connectionPool.getConnection().then(res => {
        global.db = res;
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  it('should get something from service', async () => {
    console.log(global) // contains db property from above
    const something = await Service.getSomething(10001);
    console.log(something) // { lat: null, lng: null }
    expect(something.lat).toBeCloseTo(40.7537); // fails since null isn't equal to 40.7537
    expect(something.lng).toBeCloseTo(73.9992); // fails since null isn't equal to 73.9992
  });
});
```

And this function I'm testing

```js
// Service
static async getSomething(something) {
    try {
      console.log(something) // 10001
      const [something] = await global.db.query(`SELECT lat, lng FROM geo_city WHERE zips LIKE :something`, {
        zipcode: `%${something}%`
      });
      console.log('here'); // doesn't get to here. I'm assuming the query above is failing because global.db is undefined still?
      return something;
    } catch (err) {
      return { lat: null, lng: null }; // returns this instead
    }
  }
```

I should be expecting an object whose properties are not null. Even when I add and pass `global`as a parameter to the `getSomething` method, it still fails at `await global.db.query`. Any advice on what I'm doing wrong? The Service works when I use this in the context of making a call to my API. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
try {
  global.db = mysql.createPool(config).promise();

} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Hope this helped.